# Utility for parsing /proc/net/route

Tags: linux

Is there an available utility to parse the content of `/proc/net/route` into more human readable format (i.e. dotted decimal for addresses)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ROUTE(8)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/route/) does exactly that if you invoke it with `-n` flag. Moreover, it could be used on systems without [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) support. For example:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: I agree, just execute the "route" command. The various /proc/net things are really a private(ish) interface for these utilities to use anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays you should be using the `ip route list` command instead of `route`.

Comment: Why should it be used instead of route? I think route is much easier to read/parse.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `/sbin/route` command.

Answer (score 0):

libnetlink may be the right way to go for this. I know it is the "proper" interface for a lot of low-level and physical network stuff, I'm not 100% sure about route tables, though.

See: libnetlink netlink rtnetlink